# Vuetify make date picker required and do not allow text input

Tags: html, vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify to do a date picker for a user's birthday.  I want the date picker to be required in my form and to accept date values only.  Here is what I have tried:

```
<v-flex xs12>
  <v-menu
    ref="menu"
    v-model="menu"
    :rules="requiredRules"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    full-width
    min-width="290px"
  >
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-text-field
      :rules="requiredRules"
      v-model="date"
      label="Birthday date"
      append-icon="event"
      outlined
      readonly
      v-on="on"
    ></v-text-field>
  </template>
  <v-date-picker
    ref="picker"
    v-model="date"
    :max="new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)"
    min="1950-01-01"
    @change="save"
  ></v-date-picker>
 </v-menu>
</v-flex>
```

```
    export default {    
      data() {
        return {
          requiredRules: [v => !!v || "This field is required"],
        }
      }
    }
```

With this code I can't type text into the date field box, but it doesn't appear to be required.

If I remove `readonly` then it becomes required but I am able to type text into the date field box although my required rules are still applied.

How can I make the date field box both required and not accepting of text?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you set an initial value on the `date` model, this `required` rule is probably not needed anymore since the only component responsible for updating the value is the datepicker (unless it can be set elsewhere, somehow).

Comment: I did not set an initial value on the date model. It is a birthday input, so I do not want a user accidentally forgetting to update it.

Comment: How are you validating the input elements? Do you nest them in a `v-form`? If it's initially empty, the validation should work when you focus out of the text field.

Comment: Yes, I nest them in a v-form.  Other input elements inside the form adhere to the required rules when I focus out of the text field.  It's only the date picker text field that's wrapped in a v-menu that doesn't cooperate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add the rules to `v-text-field`

```
<v-menu v-model="datemenu">
  <template v-slot:activator="{on}">
    <v-text-field
      v-model="date"
      v-on="on"
      label="Something"
      :rules="[v => !!v || 'Required']"
    ></v-text-field>
  </template>
  <v-date-picker v-model="date" @input></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

Comment: slight correction "v!!" should be "!!v"
:rules="[v => !!v || 'Required']"